# avplayer not loading https url

Tags: swift, avplayer, ios11, xcode9-beta

Downloaded ios 11 beta 2 today, app is not loading urls coming from facebook.

I thought it was related to app transport security but since urls are linking to https adresses it shouldn't be a problem?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So apple developper certificate was expired and it seems an unsigned app cannot load https url with avplayer.

As long as you don't choose another team to sign your app you will still try to sign it with your previous team even though the certificate is expired and you won't have an error at compile time, which is why I didn't see it in the first place